# how to display default value in the vf page using apex;inputfield?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to display the default value of the pick list in object in visual Force page using apex:inputfield ?

Comment: Yes, are you facing any challenges?

Comment: if you set default in field level in VF page inputfield will handle that. Are you getting any exception?

Comment: no i am not getting any exception.can u explain what is meant by setting default value in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you need to make describe call and populate the selected value with it.

Lets assume you are holding value of selected country in selectedCountry varible then you need to call below method from constructor in order to show default picklist value for country picklist.
**Code snippet:**

```
public void selectDeafultCountry()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
        OfficeLocation__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
      if(f.isDefaultValue()){
        selectedCountry = f.getValue();break;
      }
   }       
   return options;
}
```

**Ref:**
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm

Answer (score 1):

To display default value, assign the default value from controller method.

Picklist__c = "default value";

Comment: can u explain briefly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the default value from the constructor of controller:
In Controller:

```
m_objShipMethod = [Select Id, ShippingMethod__c from Shipping_Method__c where ShippingMethod__c = 'FedEx Ground' limit 1];
m_objOrderObj = [Select Shipping_Method__c from Order__c where Shipping_Method__c = :m_objShipMethod.Id limit 1];
```

In the VF page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!m_objOrderObj.Shipping_Method__c}" styleClass="textbox"/>
```

for more information please see the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098FeIAI)